# Python: What is the sense of class instantiation without variable

Tags: python, oop, instantiation, instance-variables

Why can I do

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

MyApp().run()
```

instead of doing

```
    instance = MyApp()

    instance.run()
```

I am fairly new to OOP and was fairly confused when I saw stuff written in the way of the first code snippet. Is there a reason why this seems so common?

is there a functional difference between the two?

Comment: Less typing, especially if you're never going to reuse that `instance` variable after calling `.run` on it. We're just lazy and, in this case, don't need/want to retain the instance in a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically doing the same thing in the first code block as in the second.
The difference is that in the first one **you can't reuse the instantiated MyApp() class again**.

In the second example however you define a object that can be reused.

**EDIT**

As @arekolek stated:

If you use MyApp.run() instead of assigning it to a variable, **Python will free the memory occupied by the object as soon as the call for the method run() is finished.**

p.s: I am not a pro at python might be mistaken...

Comment: You are not mistaken.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you are no longer under suspense :)

Answer (score 0):

It is more than just not being able to reuse the instantiated `MyApp()` object.

Using `MyApp.run()` instead of assigning it to a variable lets Python free the memory occupied by the object as soon as `run()` invocation is finished.

In the second example, you need to manually `del instance` if you want to free the memory. The memory will also be freed once you leave the block where the `instance` has been defined. For example:

```
def foo():
    instance = MyApp()
    instance.run()

foo()
# Memory freed automatically

instance = MyApp()
instance.run()
del instance

MyApp().run() # No need to clean-up
```

Comment: Is this true? I'd assume that the `run` method is going to need the instance in every loop, not allowing the memory to be collected.

Comment: By "every loop" you mean each of the three invocations in my example? Each `run()` in my code uses a distinct instance of the `MyApp` class, so yes it's true.

Comment: Consider a class with an instance variable `count` and an instance method `run`. The body of `run` increments `count`, prints that value, waits a second, and then invokes itself. Once `run` is invoked, the instance cannot be collected since it is still needed. In your code, `del instance` only removes `instance` from the local namespace and decrements its reference count (allowing for garbage collection when no references are left). On its own, `del` does not do anything to the actual memory used by an object.

Comment: If you are assuming that `run()` spawns a new thread and runs indefinitely (barring that you will hit recursion depth limit somewhere), then it is true what you're saying. I made the assumption that there's only one thread. But it's true the memory will be freed once `run()` is finished if you don't assign it to a variable in any case.

Comment: I get what you mean, and my comments are kind of inferring into the context of the code. It seems like OP is constructing a GUI, so either (a) `MyApp.run` is going to spawn one or many new threads, or (b) the script is going to exit soon or immediately after `MyApp.run` is *complete* (i.e. the GUI is killed).